# How to show a popup inside a scrollPane javafx

Tags: popup, javafx-2, java-7

I have some nodes in the content of a scrollPane.
With nodes mouse pressing , a popup is shown and is positioned in the required X and Y. 
Well , when scrolling , the popup is always fixed , as it is positioned according to the scene. 
Is it possible to show the popup inside the scrollPane , so when scrolling , the popup scrolls too .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for the pop-up location to track the scroll position of the scroll pane.  I am not going to write the code for that here.

One consideration you will have is what to do with the pop-up if the user scrolls such that the pop-up ends up outside the visible region of the scroll pane (I'm guessing the pop-up would then be hidden and cease tracking the scroll pane location).

Do consider your design and decide if you really need a pop-up or not, or if you can just place a node in the group that maintains the content for the scroll pane.  Because, if you did that rather than using a pop-up, then the scroll pane would automatically scroll the node in the group as it scrolled around the group.

Comment: You're right. May be I should reconsider my design and use another component. I know that popup scrolling is possible when tracking the scroll position, but I thought that maybe there's another solution for that.